# AngluarJS filter table population by user id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to filter a GET call by user id.  I keep getting an error that says the userId is undefined.  I'm not entirely sure how to properly set up my factory.  Do I need to put a getter and setter in my factory?

Factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('homeFactory',['$http', function($http){
            return{

                // GETS current user that is logged in.
                getCurrentUser: function(){
                    return $http.get("user/getCurrent")
                },

                getAllReports: function(userId){
                    return $http.get('report/user/' + userId)
                }
            }
    }])
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('homeController',
        ['$scope', '$compile', '$element', 'homeFactory','toastr', 
         function($scope, $compile, $element, homeFactory, toastr){

    // Retrieves the current user that is logged into the app.
    $scope.getCurrentUser = homeFactory.getCurrentUser().then(
    function(success){
        $scope.currentUser = success.data;
    },
    function(error){
        $scope.currentUser = error;
    });

    //Trying to get all reports by the userId
    $scope.getAllReports = homeFactory.getAllReports($scope.currentUser).then(
    function(success){
        $scope.reportName = success.data;
        console.log(reportName);
        },
    function(error){
        $scope.reportName = error;
    }); 

}])
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just put

```
$scope.getAllReports = homeFactory.getAllReports($scope.currentUser).then(
function(success){
    $scope.reportName = success.data;
    console.log(reportName);
},
function(error){
    $scope.reportName = error;
});
```

inside first promise success function:

```
function(success){
    $scope.currentUser = success.data;
}
```

Comment: hm, i understand your reasoning, however, it still doesn't do a good call back to my backend.  It's returning a 400 error:  GET http://localhost:8080/report/user/[object%20Object]

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out.  Thank you very much Mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getCurrentUser = homeFactory.getCurrentUser().then(
function(success){
    $scope.currentUser = success.data;
    console.log($scope.currentUser);
    $scope.getAllReports = homeFactory.getAllReports($scope.currentUser.userId).then(
            function(success){
                $scope.reportName = success.data;
                console.log()
                },
            function(error){
                $scope.reportName = error;
            }); 
},
function(error){
    $scope.currentUser = error;
});
```